# Using Apex to query Country Picklist Integration Values

Tags: apex, describefieldresult, country-and-state

We are using global country picklist in our org.  For historical reasons, some of our countries have a difference in the name of the country and the integration value of the country. From Apex, I tried to use User.Countrycode.getDescribe() to get the integration values, but it does not appear to be available.  So is there a way to get the integration value from Apex?

Comment: This article explains how to get the values. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338321&type=1&mode=1

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, and it only gives the value and the label, not the integration value.  I'm trying to see IF there's a way to get the integration value.

Comment: Then I’m not completely sure about getting the integration value in apex. I know that it is available through the metadata api.